# how to get blob object from createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, blob

I have an application where the user can record some audio. 
I play the recorded audio using an url generated from blob object `URL.creatObjectURL`, then the user can play and choose the audio.

I need to append the chosen audio to a FormData. I've read that it's possible to upload a blob object using XHR, but I need to get the blob back from the url generated previously.

Is there a way to extract the blob from a url like: `blob:https://domain.com/some_random_string` ?

I tried to google it, but no results. I think I'm missing something in my search keywords. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: you can probably use ajax to fetch the binary url contents, or save a ref to the blob you fed to URL.creat....

Comment: i already save blob objects as global array, but im asking if there is any other methods to avoid that, i already use urls so if i can extract blob from the url, it will better !

Comment: not really, there's no direct or hidden connection. you could use one object to store them all, keyed by url, so that you can say `blob=urls[strBlobUrl]`

Comment: sorry, i don't get your idea. i already have the blob url i can (or not) get the blob back from the url ?

Comment: you can use ajax to fetch the contents of a url.

Comment: can you post an example code, please ?

Comment: @dandavis thank you i do what you suggest and it work.